# Choose table to join in oracle depending on data

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Let's say I have 3 table `transaction`,`cust_type_1`,`cust_type_2`.

```
   Transaction  
Cust_type   char - type of customer which can be 1 or 2
Cust_id number - id from their respective table i.e. cust_type_1 and cust_type2
Amount  number - amount

   Cust_type_1  
ct1_id  number - id(pk)
ct1_name    varchar - customer name


   Cust_type_2  
ct2_id  number - id(pk)
ct2_name varchar - customer name
```

Now i wish to see create a view where i can see name and amount only.

```
select COND_JOINED_TABLE_ALIAS.name,t.amount
from   transaction t
join   case when t.type = 1 JOIN CUST_TYPE_1
       else JOIN CUST_TYPE_2 END AS COND_JOINED_TABLE_ALIAS
```

How can i achieve conditional join based on type of data.
Yes i know there can be better structure to avoid this use case. But this is just for example.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do your case in the select directly:

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN t.type=1
    THEN cust1.ct1_name
    ELSE cust2.ct2_name
  END AS Customer_name ,
  t.amount
FROM transaction t
JOIN Cust_type_1 cust1
ON t.Cust_id = cust1.ct1_id
JOIN Cust_type_2 cust2
ON t.Cust_id = cust2.ct2_id;
```

Comment: i believe it should be left outer join rather than inner join as the above query will not yield the records for transaction.cust_id value which does not exist in both cust_type_1 and cust_type_2 tables

Answer (score 1):

Hope below snippet helps.

```
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN T.TYPE = 1
    THEN
      (SELECT CTL_NAME FROM CUST_TYPE_1 A WHERE T.CUST_ID = A.CTL_ID
      )
    WHEN T.TYPE = 2
    THEN
      (SELECT CTL_NAME FROM CUST_TYPE_2 B WHERE T.CUST_ID = B.CTL_ID
      )
  END nme,
  T.AMOUNT
FROM transaction t;
```

Answer (score 0):

below sql can be used

```
SELECT
    CASE t.cust_type
        WHEN 1   THEN c1.ct1_name
        WHEN 2   THEN c2.ct2_name
    END
AS cust_name,
t.amount
FROM
transaction t
LEFT JOIN cust_type_1 c1 ON t.cust_id = c1.ct1_id
LEFT JOIN cust_type_2 c2 ON t.cust_id = c2.ct2_id
```